# Discontinuing page numbering: Hyperlinks in the index of a document don't work properly

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, hyperlink

My code:

```
\documentclass[
               titlepage,
               abstract
              ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[intoc]

\title{Test}
\dedication{Test.}

\begin{document}

  \maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
    Test.
  \end{abstract}

  \pagenumbering{Roman}
  \tableofcontents
  \newpage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}

  \section{Test}
    Das Zweistrom-Turbinen-Luftstrahltriebwerk (ZTL)\index{ZTL}~\ldots

  \newpage
  \pagenumbering{Roman}
  \setcounter{page}{2}
  \printindex

\end{document}
```

The table of contents should start with big Roman one. The text part (in the MWE starts with the test section) should start with an arabic one. This works.

But if I click in the index on the link, then it jumps to the title page (physical page one). I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but if I comment out the lines, which have to do with the page numbering (twice `\pagenumbering{Roman}`, `\pagenumbering{arabic}` and `\setcounter{page}{2}`), than it have the expected behavior. At the same time the hyperlinks in the table of contents work every time.

Why is it so and how can I fix this?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: `\pagenumbering{arabic}` resets the page counter. so your index entry is linked to page 1 in your entire document, which is the title page.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}`

Comment: Hello @esdd! Thank you for your comment! Sorry, but `hypertexnames=false` changes nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1})
has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

and the problem is that the title page shares number 1 with the one where `\section{Test}` appears.

Add `\pagenumbering{Alph}` for the front matter pages. Also it's cleaner to use `\clearpage` rather than `\newpage` before changing the page numbering style.

```
\documentclass[
  titlepage,
  abstract
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[intoc]

\title{Test}
\dedication{Test.}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Alph}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Test.
\end{abstract}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Test}

Das Zweistrom-Turbinen-Luftstrahltriebwerk (ZTL)\index{ZTL}~\ldots

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like that, just with  `\pagenumbering{Roman} \pagenumbering{arabic}` just after packages

```
\documentclass[
               titlepage,
               abstract
              ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
  \pagenumbering{Roman}
 \pagenumbering{arabic}
\makeindex[intoc]

\title{Test}
\dedication{Test.}

\begin{document}

  \maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
    Test.
  \end{abstract}


  \tableofcontents
  \newpage


  \section{Test}
    Das Zweistrom-Turbinen-Luftstrahltriebwerk (ZTL)\index{ZTL}~\ldots

  \newpage
  \pagenumbering{Roman}
  \setcounter{page}{2}
  \printindex

\end{document}
```

Jeremy

Comment: Hello @Jérémy Spark Fraissenet! Thank for your answer! The table of contents should have `Roman` page numbering too. Your suggestion didn't unaccounted for it.