# hyperref, makeidx and autonum combination leads to unexpected results

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, warnings, hyperlink, makeidx

This question is a follow-up of my [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437651/discontinuing-page-numbering-hyperlinks-in-the-index-of-a-document-dont-work-p):

1. If I use math equations with the `autonum` package and the `hyperref` package without setting the option `hypertexnames` to `false` then I receive those warnings:

   a. pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier
   (name{equation.X.X.X}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

   b. pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier
   (name{page.X}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

The second warning doesn't appear in my MWE below. I couldn't figure out which piece of my original code produce this warning, sorry for it. **Note**: The index linking works properly.

2. If I set the `hyperref` option `hypertexnames` to `false` than those
   warnings don't appear, **but** the index linking doesn't work properly
   (it links to the physical page one, which is the title page).
3. If I don't use the `autonum` package than the equation counting of the `\[\]` environment doesn't work at all and the equation
   linking (referencing) is particular wrong (in my MWE the equation
   `P_F = F v` gets the same link number as the equation `P_N = \dot m
   w_N`). **Note**: The index linking works properly, if I don't set the
   `hypertexnames` option to `false`, but than I have again above
   warnings.

I tried to cut as much as possible, but I don't know precise enough where the warnings appear, so my MWE is not really minimal, sorry for this. So if some one have the experience, to find out where the warnings come from, feel free to cut my MWE:

```
\documentclass[
               twoside,
               titlepage,
               abstract,
               ngerman
              ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
            lmodern,
            babel,
            makeidx,
            graphicx
           }
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{autonum}

\makeindex

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

  \pagenumbering{Alph}
  \maketitle

  \begin{abstract}
    Abstract.
  \end{abstract}
  \cleardoublepage

  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\Roman{page}}
  \tableofcontents
  \cleardoublepage

  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \chapter{Chapter}
    \section{Section one}
      Siehe Seite \pageref{Vortriebswirkungsgrad}\index{eta}.

    \section{Section two}
      \subsubsection{Vortriebswirkungsgrad}\label{Vortriebswirkungsgrad}
        \[\eta_p = \frac{P_F}{| P_N |}\label{eta_P}\]

      \subsubsection{Effizienzsteigerung eines Triebwerkes}\label{eta_g}
        \[\eta_g = \eta_t \eta_p\]

      \subsubsection{Schubleistung}
        \[P_F = F v\label{P_F}\]

      \subsubsection{Spezifische Nutzarbeit}
        \begin{align}
          w_N &= c_p \eta_t ( T_4 - T_3 )\label{w_N}\\
          P_N &= \dot m w_N.\label{P_N}
        \end{align}

      \subsubsection{Spezifischer Brennstoffverbrauch}
        \[B_s = \frac{\dot m_B}{F}.\]

      \subsubsection{Nebenstromverhältnis}\label{mu}
        \[\mu = \frac{\dot m_2}{\dot m_1}.\]

      \subsubsection{Maßnahmen für ZTL}
        \begin{align}
          P_F &= \eta_p | P_N |,
          \intertext{die Nutzleistung, aus Gleichung \eqref{P_N} auf Seite \pageref{P_N}, eingesetzt:}
              &= \eta_p | \dot m w_N |
          \intertext{und schließlich noch die spezifische Nutzarbeit, aus Gleichung \eqref{w_N} auf Seite \pageref{w_N}, ersetzt:}
              &= \eta_p | c_p\eta_t ( T_4 - T_3 ) |.
          \intertext{Außerdem gilt die Gleichung \eqref{P_F}, auf Seite \pageref{P_F}, nach wie vor:}
              &= F v.
        \end{align}

  \cleardoublepage
  \pagenumbering{Roman}
  \setcounter{page}{7}
  \printindex

\end{document}
```

What do I wrong and why is it so? Can I use all three packages without described issues?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: Well autonum redefines all the math environments and so it should define a sensible \theHequation instead of going the easy way and telling people to use hypertexnames=false. Complain to the package author.

Comment: Hello @Ulrike Fischer! Thank you for your comment! Not good. Is there a way to solve this task (use of all three packages without warnings and correct results)?

Comment: Sure, I already told you what to do: Complain to the package author.

Comment: Hello @Ulrike Fischer! Is the email-address given in the readme functional [one](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/autonum)?

Comment: No idea, try it out. If it bounces you will know ...

Comment: Hello @Ulrike Fischer! Sorry for the long delay. I sended an email to the author.

Comment: Update. Hello @Ulrike Fischer! I send an email to the author for a total of five times and received no answer. So, I give up at this point...